# import spacy google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-colab, spacy

Estoy empezando a trabajar en Google COLAB y debo importar spaCy, sin embargo no funciona. Yo escribo

```
!pip install spacy
!python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm
```

Todo va bien y al final me escribe

```
Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('fr_core_news_sm')
```

Sin embargo cuando escribo la siguiente linea me da error que sigue

```
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_sm')

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'fr_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a 
shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

¿Existe alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, alguien me dio la respuesta. Lo probé y funciona. Hay que crear un **link**. Seria:

```
!python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm
!python -m spacy link fr_core_news_sm fr
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para Google colab puedes utilizar el método pip, pero yo te recomiendo utilizar la manera que permite importar en Google Colab dándole un nombre. Para tu caso, he utilizado la abreviación spc. Esto quiere decir que cada vez que quieres utilizarlo, tendrás que "invocarlo" con esta expresión. El código quedaría asi:

```
import spacy as spc
```

Por tanto el comando *load* que quieres utiliar deberá sustituir el spacy original por la abreviación, ya que es lo que Google colab entiende por él:

```
nlp = spc.load('fr_core_news_sm')
```

Comment: No lo entiendo, sigue dando el mismo error

`OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'fr_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.`

Answer (score 0):

Algo que me sirvió a mi en Google Colab fue hacer esto

```
!python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
import es_core_news_sm
nlp = es_core_news_sm.load()
```